# Fail to compile webpack when I run ruby server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack

I have try to run my ruby server and I got this error :

```
[Webpacker] Compiling...
[Webpacker] Compilation failed:
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/webpacker/runner.rb:13:in ``': No such file or directory - yarn (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/webpacker/runner.rb:13:in `initialize'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/webpacker/runner.rb:6:in `new'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/webpacker/runner.rb:6:in `run'
    from ./bin/webpack:17:in `block in <main>'
    from ./bin/webpack:16:in `chdir'
    from ./bin/webpack:16:in `<main>'
```

I have search how to fix it on the internet but nobody has the same as me. And when I try to update my stylesheet that not works.

Realy don't know where that could come from. And the file where the error is is not file that I have make so I don't dare to edit them.

I have try to remove my node_module folder reinit with yarn but nothing change and I got the same error.

Comment: can you add more info about project, gemfile, rails and ruby version? Does `yarn install --check-files` runs without an error?

Comment: I have yarn V1.22.10, ruby 2.7, rails 6.1.3.1.
When I run `yarn install --check-files` I don't have error, just this two warning : 
`warning " > webpack-dev-server@3.11.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.3" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
`

Comment: I had similar problem. But I was able to compile it from command line, even with `rake assets:precompile`. Finally I've reinstalled the yarn -> `npm i -g yarn`